# How do I update my git when files are changed directly on the server?

Tags: git, github

One of the resources have updated and made changes directly on the server of our site.

What should I do to make sure that my local and git are all updated with server files?

When I did a `git status` after an ssh on my server, I get this:-

```
On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#
#   modified:   sites/all/themes/xxx/css/styles.css
#   modified:   sites/all/themes/xxx/css/styles-print.css
#   modified:   sites/all/themes/xxx/templates/views/views-view--all-documents--block.tpl.php
#   modified:   sites/all/themes/mso/templates/views/views-view--all-articles--block.tpl.php
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to commit the changes and then push them. After that, pull the changes in your local repository.

In your server:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Your message"
git push
```

In your local repository:

```
git pull
```